# Unexpected @using keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I want to make strongly typed view. Somehow the `@using` tag is not being recognised by the Razor Engine and will give me a parser error on run-time:
`Unexpected "using" keyword after "@" character.
Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "using" with "@".`

This is what I've got:

```
@{
    @using MyNamespace.ViewModels  // Parser error shows this line.
    @model EmployeeViewModel       // MyNamespace.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel alone works.
}

(omitted code)

Employee Name : @Model.EmployeeName <br />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model declaration needs to come before any other code. Following that, you can simply just use the using statement on its own.

```
@model EmployeeViewModel 
@using MyNamespace.ViewModels

(omitted code)

Employee Name : @Model.EmployeeName <br />
```

Comment: Tried to switch the positions of the two, but that didn't work. I saw you didn't put the `@{ }` around the declarations and removing these did the trick. The `model` and `using` declaration positions don't seem to matter.

Comment: @Tom - Yes, removing the `@{}` is important which is why it is not in this answer. Using `@{}` creates a scope which executes c# code. It is no longer scoped to razor helpers.

Comment: it's never too late to accept this answer, isn't it? I guess I forgot.

Comment: @Tom - Well it certainly is appreciated. Usually I upvote a question if I post an answer seeing as how if it is answerable I figure it should get an upvote, and didn't here for some reason, so hey you got +7 for marking this as accepted :)